# How to change title font size in moderncv?

Tags: fontsize, titles, moderncv

How can I change the title font size (First name, Family Name) in a resume written using [`moderncv`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/moderncv) package?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

It is controlled by `\namefont`, so you just need to redefine that. As an example, the standard definition for the `casual` style is:

```
\renewcommand*{\namefont}{\fontsize{38}{40}\mdseries\upshape}
```

Similarly, the following macros control the fonts of other elements (the macro names should speak for themselves): `\titlefont`, `\addressfont`, `\quotefont`, `\sectionfont`, `\subsectionfont`, `\hintfont` and `\pagenumberfont`.

Comment: This worked. Thanks! Does the second number (40) indicate the spacing left after title? Also, what do mdseries and upshape stand for?

Comment: First of all: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). As you seem new around here, just note that people generally prefer that you post [follow-up questions](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2117) as fresh new ones rather than as comments; this enables the question to be searched and its answer(s) to be reused by others. That being said, `\fontsize` takes as arguments the size of the font and of the linespace (so the second number controls the spacing after, but only if there is a `\par` to use the new linespace AFAIK).

Comment: `\mdseries` stands for medium bold weight (as compared to bold, light, extra bold, etc.), and `\upshape` for upright font variant (as compared to italics or oblique / slanted).