# How to reduce name and title font in moderncv on TeX Live 2016?

Tags: moderncv

An [SO answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/128054/9549) suggests that the size of namefont and titlefont can be reduced by replacing 38/40.

```
\renewcommand*{\namefont}{\fontsize{38}{40}\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\titlefont}{\fontsize{38}{40}\mdseries\upshape}
```

A post on [latex-community.org](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=25906) suggests that hacking moderncvstylebanking.sty by replacing `\huge` is the way to do it.

```
\renewcommand*{\namefont}{\huge\bfseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\titlefont}{\huge\mdseries\upshape}
```

Moderncv has been restructured and the second option no longer applies. The first, used in the following MWE, doesn't work. How can I reduce name and title font in moderncv on TeX Live 2016?

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/128054/9549
\renewcommand*{\namefont}{\fontsize{14}{18}\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\titlefont}{\fontsize{14}{18}\mdseries\upshape}

\moderncvstyle{banking}
\name{First}{Last}
\title{Resumé Title}

\begin{document}
\recipient{Bob Inc.}{Bob}
\opening{Dear Bob,}
\closing{Yours truly,}

\makelettertitle
\lipsum[1]
\makeletterclosing
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\moderncvstyle{banking}` also sets these fonts. So issue your font changing after that.

```
\moderncvstyle{banking}
\renewcommand*{\namefont}{\fontsize{14}{18}\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\titlefont}{\fontsize{14}{18}\mdseries\upshape}
```