# Reduce name and familyname size in moderncv

Tags: fontsize, moderncv

I am using moderncv template to write my first CV (I am a newbie). Question is easy: I would like to reduce the size of name and familyname on the top of the page. How can I do it?

In my preamble, I have:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,colorlinks,linkcolor=true, sans]{moderncv}
%\renewcommand*{\namefont}{\fontsize{14}{18}\mdseries\upshape}
%\renewcommand*{\titlefont}{\fontsize{14}{18}\mdseries\upshape}

\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

% alcuni pacchetti standard
\usepackage[italian]{babel} % solo se si scrive in italiano
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=1.8cm,bottom=2.2cm]{geometry}

% questa riga allarga la colonna di sinistra
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3.7cm}




% personal data
\firstname{Michele}
\familyname{Belladonna}
\title{Curriculum Vitae}
\address{Via Piave 40}{81030, Cesa (CE), Italia}
\mobile{+39\,3881268452}
\email{michelebelladonna86@gmail.com}

\AtBeginDocument{\hypersetup{colorlinks, urlcolor=blue}}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128052/how-to-change-title-font-size-in-moderncv Does this help?

Comment: It works! I was wrong because I have written `\renewcommand*{\namefont}{\fontsize{14}{18}\mdseries\upshape}` after \documentclass and not before \begin{document}. Thanks.

Comment: Please @carlosvalderrama can you suggest me a good reference (possibly short) to write a CV in LateX? I mean, to add lines to the basic template. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As to the reference, the tutorial here

https://vic.demuzere.be/articles/curriculum-vitae-cv-with-latex-moderncv/

offers a short description how lines are added.